# QGIS 3.2 - How do I join road segments together like they're shown in a Road Map/Atlas?

Tags: qgis-plugins, road

When I imported any of my Roads Layers ESRI Shapefiles from OS Vector District data into QGIS 3.2 using one of the pre-defined Road Symbol representations,
I get a very poor result showing the road as hundreds of little bits with the cap ends, rather than a continuous flow like an OS Raster Map.

There seems to be NO "open-ended" join for the Road Symbol Properties - only a "rounded end cap" or a "square end cap" is offered!

Can anyone advise me:-

1) Is there a ready-made tutorial that shows this? I saw a You Tube Video showing something like but the presenter did it much too quickly for me to follow how he did it!

2) Is there a ready made "plugin" to do this function, that will also join up road junctions correctly?

Answer (score 1):

You use Symbol Levels to achieve this, which is found under the Advanced drop-down in the symbology panel. After enabling Symbol Levels, simply assign a higher number to your road fill symbol and a lower number to your road casing symbol. This will cause the capped ends of the segments to be hidden behind the solid fill. (And make sure you do in fact have a fill assigned to your road symbol, even if it's just opaque white.

Here is a YouTube tutorial that shows this procedure (towards the middle of the video):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NVu-KVgwbbs